# ¿Por qué la terminal me lanza ese error al trata de instalar passport-jwt en node?

Tags: nodejs

```
npm i passport-jwt
```

> npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near
>   '...0","passport-strategy'
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:  npm ERR!
>   /home/oscary/.npm/_logs/2020-03-26T02_43_14_781Z-debug.log

Answer (score 0):

Para esos casos puedes limpiar el proyecto, ya que al hacer varias instalaciones y/o actualizaciones hacen que tu node tenga archivos corruptos dentro del caché, para eso sigue estos pasos.

Ejecuta con sudo: `npm cache clean --force`

Luego borra la carpeta `node_modules` y el archivo `package-lock.json`

Y al final instala todo nuevamente en tu proyecto:
`npm i` o `npm install`

Comment: Muchísimas gracias Synay me funciono perfectamente.